# Subquery in SELECT, count and case using Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2

i have query like this to count `location_id` in my `member_location` table

```
$stat_location = Location::find()
    ->select([
        '*',
        'jum1' => MemberLocation::find()
            ->select(['COUNT(*)'])
            ->from('member_location') 
            ->where(['=','a.id','member_location.location_id']),
    ])
    ->alias('a')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

and thats query  worked.
In my `Location` table there is a `capacity` column, now i want to get the status full or not based on amount/count `location_id` in `member_location` table.
I have try query like this

```
$stat_location = Location::find()
    ->select([
        '*',
        'jum1' => MemberLocation::find()
            ->select(['COUNT(*)'])
            ->from('member_location') 
            ->where(['=','a.id','member_location.location_id']),
        'status' => "(CASE WHEN jum1 > a.capacity THEN 'full'  ELSE  'available' END)",
    ])
    ->alias('a')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

But that query give me a error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jum1' in 'field list'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `member_location` WHERE  (`a`.`id` = 'member_location.location_id')) AS `jum1`, (CASE WHEN jum1 > a.capacity THEN 'full' ELSE 'available' END) AS `status` FROM `location` `a`
```

Any help?, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not use an alias from the SELECT statement in the WHERE clause. You can, however, use it in the HAVING clause.

Alternatively (a better alternative for your example), move the subquery from the SELECT statement to left or inner join.